# before hook is called twice in Cypress.io test

Tags: cypress

For some reason, the hook before is called twice. It works well without cy. calls. Before a test case with cy. logic it calls the hook at the second. This is a trivial error that I have been resolving for a week.

Comment: Here  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2636 the issue is described. The runner is reloaded after cy.visit command because the page is reloaded.